# HttpSecurity file do not have method oauth2Login()

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

> I am doing Spring Security Oauth2. In client side I override
>   `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method and want to use `oauth2Login()`
>   method in HttpSecurity file. But HttpSecurity do not have this
>   function. I already add dependency of `spring-security-oauth2-client,
>   spring-boot-starter-security and spring-security-oauth2` in pom.xml. 
>   In `HttpSecurity` file it writes "Copyright 2002-2016 the original
>   author or authors". How can i update this?

```
    @EnableWebSecurity
     public class OauthConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure your spring-boot-starter-parent version is correct.
The below is a sample:
**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>your-artifactId</artifactId>
<version>your-version</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--if you need to generate token-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>



<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>


</project>
```

How to configure WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class:

1.with **default** implementations:

```
@Configuration
public class SimpleTestSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login();
    }
}
```

2. with **customized** implementation for `loginPage`, `authorizationEndpoint` , `TokenEndpoint`, `redirectionEndpoint`, `userInfoEndpoint`:

```
    @Configuration
    public class SimpleTestSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        private String[] PERMIT_ALL = {"unsecured-endpoint1", "unsecured-endpoint2", "..."};

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(PERMIT_ALL).permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .oauth2Login()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
                    .failureUrl("/error")

                    .authorizationEndpoint()
                    .baseUri("/oauth2/authorize-client") //default is "/oauth2/authorization"
                    .and()

                    .tokenEndpoint()
                    .accessTokenResponseClient(accessTokenResponseClient())
                    .and()

                    //.redirectionEndpoint()
                    //.baseUri("/oauth2/redirect") //base for google is "/login/oauth2/code"
                    //.and()

                    .userInfoEndpoint().oidcUserService(new OidcUserService(){
                        @Override
                        public OidcUser loadUser(OidcUserRequest userRequest) throws OAuth2AuthenticationException {
                            return super.loadUser(userRequest);
                        }
            });

        }

        @Bean
        public AuthorizationRequestRepository<OAuth2AuthorizationRequest> authorizationRequestRepository(){
            return new HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository();
        }


        @Bean
        public OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient<OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequest> accessTokenResponseClient(){
            return new NimbusAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient();
        }

    }
```

3. application.yml :

```
    spring:
        security:
            oauth2:
                client:
                    registration:
                        google:
                            client-id: your-client-id
                            client-secret: your-client-secret
                            redirectUriTemplate: "http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/google"
                            scope:
                                - email
                                - profile
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using spring boot you can use the following dependencies to auto configure the spring security for oauth2:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

After adding the above dependency if you want to override anything.The Spring Boot 2.x auto-configuration class for OAuth Client support is *OAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration*.

It performs the following tasks:

- Registers a ClientRegistrationRepository ***@Bean*** composed of
  ClientRegistration(s) from the configured OAuth Client properties.
- Provides a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter ***@Configuration*** and enables
  OAuth 2.0 Login through ***httpSecurity.oauth2Login().***

If you need to override the auto-configuration based on your specific requirements, you may do so in the following ways:

- Register a ClientRegistrationRepository @Bean
- Provide a ***WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter***
- Completely Override the Auto-configuration

By overrriding ***WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter*** is as follows:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2LoginSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .oauth2Login()
                .clientRegistrationRepository(this.clientRegistrationRepository())
                .authorizedClientService(this.authorizedClientService())
                .loginPage("/login")
                .authorizationEndpoint()
                    .baseUri(this.authorizationRequestBaseUri())
                    .authorizationRequestRepository(this.authorizationRequestRepository())
                    .and()
                .redirectionEndpoint()
                    .baseUri(this.authorizationResponseBaseUri())
                    .and()
                .tokenEndpoint()
                    .accessTokenResponseClient(this.accessTokenResponseClient())
                    .and()
                .userInfoEndpoint()
                    .userAuthoritiesMapper(this.userAuthoritiesMapper())
                    .userService(this.oauth2UserService())
                    .oidcUserService(this.oidcUserService())
                    .customUserType(GitHubOAuth2User.class, "github");
    }
}
```

For reference see this :

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.7.RELEASE/reference/html/oauth2login-advanced.html

and

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html

Comment: But HttpSecurity in my project do not have method oauth2Login() so i can not use http.oauth2Login()

Comment: oauth2Login()  is a method of the class HttpSecurity  and it should be accessible for you .Can you check if you have imported the correct class and the dependencies included are correct or not ? Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html

Comment: hi can you try adding                                                       `<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
`
as dependency and rebuild the project to see if the method gets exposed or not ?

Comment: thank you i fix it by change version of spring-boot-starter-parent :))